# General-purpose program for RLE compression

Tags: compression

We have to deal with very large columnar files with fixed-size data and lots of padding bytes coming from mainframe.

I would like to evaluate different compression techniques and their impact on performance vs. disk space. For LZ77, we have gzip/gunzip/zcat, for BZIP2, we have bzip2/bunzip2 but is there a similar general-purpose program for RLE?

Comment: Yes, I've seen a lot of source-code trying to implement it or demonstrate RLE because the principle is very easy. These programs are usually limited to text characters and seems to not be very well tested. I'm looking for something well-established if something like this exists.